# least value in count

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table employee(id,dept_id,salary,hire_date,job_id) . the following query i  have to execute.

Show all the employee who were hired on the day of the week on which least no of employee were hired.

i have done the query, but am not able to get the least. please check if am correct.

```
          select id, WEEKDAY(hire_date)+1 as days,count(WEEKDAY(hire_date)+1) as count

           from test.employee  group by days
```

Comment: What's with the `1)`?  Is this your homework?

Comment: Well what then?  Is this an exam you're taking for a prospective employer?  Definitely looks sketchy... the way the question is structured, it's almost definitely from a test.  I personally don't feel good about helping someone cheat.

Comment: Ah, I see you edited your question to remove the `1)` now.  Sketchy.

Comment: am preparing for some entrance exam. this question is there in some book. so am solving it

Comment: Well maybe you should take the time to learn this stuff instead of having other people solve it for you.  You won't learn anything that way.

Comment: Here's a hint for you... you're gonna need 2 subqueries to get this done.  The innermost query gets the minimum count, the one outside that gets the day associated with that min count, and the outermost query gets the employees hired on that day.  Think of the results in datasets.

Comment: What if you have just either 1 employee hired on each Monday, Tuesday and Friday for e.g.? Don't you want to show the count as 1 and ALL those weekdays with least number of hire?

Comment: have to show the emp id of the hired employee and not count

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the weekday on which the least number of employees were hired:

```
SELECT 
   count(id) as `Total`,
   WEEKDAY(hire_date) as `DoW`
FROM
   test.employee
GROUP BY `DoW`
ORDER BY `Total` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: fyi, not all databases support `group by alias`, but all support `group by 2`

Answer (score 1):

```
select id from test.employee where hire_date in
    ( select count(id) count,hire_date 
      from test.employee
      order by count desc 
      limit 1)
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, as it will not limit to one record if you have multiple week days where the same least number of employees were hired. In reality it makes sense. The following is based on *sample data.*

**Query:**

```
-- find minimum id count
SELECT MIN(e.counts) INTO @min 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as counts,
      WEEKDAY(hire_date+1) as day 
FROM employee
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(hire_date+1)) e
;

-- show weekdays with minimum id counts
SELECT e2.counts as mincount, 
WEEKDAY(e1.hire_date+1) as weekday
FROM employee e1
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) as counts, 
        WEEKDAY(hire_date+1) as day
        FROM employee 
        GROUP BY day
        HAVING COUNT(*) = @min) e2
    ON WEEKDAY(e1.hire_date+1) = e2.day;
```

**Results:**

```
MINCOUNT    WEEKDAY
1           6
1           3
1           4
1           2
```

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13844/39)

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(id), WEEKDAY(hire_date)+1 as days,count(WEEKDAY(hire_date)+1) as count

       from test.employee  group by days
```

Comment: i want the least count, not min id

Answer (score 0):

```
       SELECT
           *
         FROM
       employee
       WHERE
          DAYOFWEEK(hire_date)
         IN 
      (
             SELECT 
            weekday 
        FROM
           (
             SELECT 
        count(*) as bcount, 
        DAYOFWEEK(hire_date) as weekday 
    FROM 
        employee as a
    GROUP BY 
        weekday
    HAVING
        bcount = (
            SELECT 
                MIN(tcount)
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                        count(*) as tcount, 
                        DAYOFWEEK(hire_date) as weekday 
                    FROM 
                        employee 
                    GROUP BY 
                        weekday

                ) as t
        )
    ) as q
```